# requested route undefined in NodeJs / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to check if a user is authorized. If not the template to render should be my login view. In my `app.js` I require my `router.js`

```
require('./server/router')(app);
```

and my router file handles the different routes.

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      if(req.route != '/login'){ // the url is not the login page
        var session = req.session;
        if (session.user == null){ // the user is not authorized
          res.render('login', {
            showHeader: false
          });
        } else { // check the next route
          next();
        }
      } else { // check the next route
        next();
      }
    });

    app.use('/route1', require('./routes/route1'));
    app.use('/route2', require('./routes/route2'));
    app.use('/route3', require('./routes/route3'));

    app.use(function(req, res, next) { // no valid route was found
      res.render('notFound', {
        showHeader: false
      });
    });
};
```

My if statement `if(req.route != '/login')` is always true, because `req.route` always returns `undefined`.

What is wrong or missing here?

Comment: where did you define app?

Comment: from ref. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html i din't see any route properity of req object

Comment: may be req.baseUrl, req.path help you

Comment: Perhaps you want `req.url`?

Comment: i guess you should use `req.url`

Comment: If you look at the [doc for `req.route`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.route), you will see that `req.route` is an object with a bunch of properties, not a string.

Comment: FYI, basic debugging when you find that `req.route != '/login'` is always true would be to look at what `req.route` actually is.  A simple `console.log(req.route)` would have showed you all you need to know.  And, a quick consult on the express doc would have also explained it.  You should have been able to solve this mystery yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can try the following methods to get uri segments.
- let suppose you have url like http://localhost/example/login

  req.baseUrl

  will get '/login'
- and if url is like http://localhost/example/admin/login

  req.originalUrl

  will get '/admin/login'

  - and

  req.path

will get '/login'

Comment: There is too a `req.route`.  It's an object with properties, not a simple path.